# Error in printing string with characters and numbers in Fortran

Tags: printing, fortran

I am new to Fortran. I am trying to print a line that has some words and numbers. I type the following command for that-

```
integer           i0lcan
integer           i0l
integer           i0rec
real              r1supdomcan(n0l)
integer           i0lcan 
if(i2lcan(i0l,1).ne.0)then
    do i0rec=1,n0rec
        i0lcan=i2lcan(i0l,i0rec)
        if(i0lcan.ne.0)then
            call calc_supcan(i0lcan,demdom(i0lcan),
 $          rivout(i0l),envflw(i0l),
 $          supdomcan(i0lcan))

print *, 'calculate_humact at the grid: ', supdomcan(i0lcan), 'supplied from the grid no: ', i0lcan
```

This produces an error that `Error: Expected expression in PRINT statement at (1)`

However, there is no error if I keep the command as-

`print *, 'calculate_humact at the grid: ', supdomcan(i0lcan)`

What could be the reason behind that?

Comment: Please show a more complete piece of code, see [ask] and [mcve]. We should be able to try your code ourselves.

Comment: Actually the original code has more than 700 lines, I am trying to print intermediate variables. What specific details do I need to add?

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Please do read the link.

Comment: We really at least need the declarations of your variables. Although my original suspicion that your line is just too long is quite likely. However, when copying the code, make sure that you also correctly show which columns are used when using fixed format. Also, always show a more complete error output. Wasn't there something more? Something about line truncation?

Comment: Added the declarations. The error line is just that only. But the problem solved when I shortened the line. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line is just too long. I supposed we might have a duplicate, but I did not find a good one.

Fixed form requires lines to use only 72 characters. Further characters on the line are just discarded.

The code you show unfortunately does not show the columns correctly.

Comment: Reducing characters in the line solved the problem. But is there no way to print more than 72 characters?

Comment: You can continue the statement on the next line. See how the call statement is continued using the `$` characters in your code samples. Any  nonblank character in the sixth column marks line continuation.

Comment: Alternatively you could stop using fixed format source and move to the new (introduced in 1990) free format which allows up to 132 characters per line